# How do I properly reshape this array?

Tags: python, numpy, reinforcement-learning

I am trying to build a RLearning agent using a old tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OYhFoMySoVs&t=2444s). I fixed a earlier bug about the old gym step function, but I can't seem to figure out how to fix the reshaping issue. If anyone has any advice it would be much appreciated.

I looked through the Numpy documentation to see if I could solve the bug but cound'nt fix it. Also I looked at the YouTube comments but there doesn't appear to be any fixes. I looked at a similar tutorial and ran into the same issue.

My Code (I didn't include the code for the DQNAgent if that is needed please ask)

````
env = gym.make('CartPole-v1')
state_size = env.observation_space.shape[0]
action_size = env.action_space.n

batch_size = 32
n_episodes = 1001

# Stores the model
output_dir = './model_output/cartpole'
if not os.path.exists(output_dir):
    os.makedirs(output_dir)```
````

```
agent = DQNAgent(state_size, action_size)

done = False
for e in range(n_episodes):
    state = env.reset()  # reset the state
    print(state)
    print([1, state_size])
    state = np.reshape(state, [1, state_size])

    for time in range(5000):  # If the game lasts 5000 time steps
        # env.render()

        action = agent.act(state)  # Get an action (0 - left, 1 - right)
        # Early this will be random, but as time passes it will be more logical (Exploiting)
        next_state, reward, done, truncated, _ = env.step(action)
        reward = reward if not done else -10  # Penalize poor actions
        next_state = np.reshape(next_state, [1, state_size])

        agent.remember(state, action, reward, next_state, done)
        state = next_state
        if done:  # To see how the agent performs if completed
            print(f"Episode: {e}/{n_episodes}, score: {time}, e: {agent.epsilon:.2}")
            break

        if len(agent.memory) > batch_size:  # Gives a chance for the agent to update
            agent.replay(batch_size)
```

Also if anyone has any other good resources for learning about reinforcement learning please share. Thank you in advance.

Edit -- The error message is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\josep\VS Code Files\Python Projects\RL_Gym\main.py", line 120, in <module>
    state = np.reshape(state, [1, state_size])
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 200, in reshape
  File "C:\Users\josep\VS Code Files\Python Projects\RL_Gym\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 298, in reshape
    return _wrapfunc(a, 'reshape', newshape, order=order)
  File "C:\Users\josep\VS Code Files\Python Projects\RL_Gym\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 54, in _wrapfunc
    return _wrapit(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\josep\VS Code Files\Python Projects\RL_Gym\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 43, in _wrapit
    result = getattr(asarray(obj), method)(*args, **kwds)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (2,) + inhomogeneous part.
```

Comment: full error message please

Comment: I just updated the question to include the error message

Comment: I see two prints right before that problem line.  Did you see those as well?  Do they tell you anything about the `state` variable?  That's what `reshape` is having problems with.  Did you also get a `VisibleDeprecationWarning` about `ragged nested sequences`?

Comment: Why do you have this `reshape` operation?  What are you trying to accomplish?  Are you trying to correct some other error (that you didn't understand either)?  Or merely copying someone else?

Comment: In numpy version 1.24, `np.asarray([[1,2,3],[4,5]])` raises this kind of error.  Previously it would have given a `VisibleDepreciationWarning` and created an object dtype.  Now you have to explicitly specify `object` dtype if that's what you want.  But if you want a numeric dtype array, you have to correct the component shapes first.